# How to create a continuous image Slideshow with Photokit on tvOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, slideshow, tvos, photokit

I created a digital signage tvOS app for my company that plays music in the background but also I want it to display our promo images on it but I don't know how to pull the promo images from the photos app or iCloud to display as a slideshow. Is this even possible and if it is, please point me in the right direction to get started. Thanks

[image]

Comment: I wonder about that too.
The graph from Apple documentation (embedded in the question) suggests that PhotoKIT can access(?) a Slideshow capability of iOS.

Can we easily implement a Slideshow in an iOS app using a PhotoKit?